# Is there a way to stream application logs to a different Stackdriver project?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm wondering if it's possible to stream application(GKE) logs not only to the StackDriver where the app exists, but to another StackDriver(Different project) at the same time.

Trying to add another fluent-d DaemonSet but don't know where to set any project info in the [fluentd-gcp-configmap-old.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp/fluentd-gcp-configmap-old.yaml) for the different project .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default, the Stackdriver output plugin for fluentd (`out_google_cloud`) writes logs into the project that owns the identity (service account) it uses to authenticate. You can [override](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#advanced_non-default_configuration_definitions) the project id in the agent configuration, as long as the identity has the permission to write logs into the destination project.

Answer (score 1):

Stackdriver logging is per project, "The Logs Viewer shows only the logs from one project" [1]. However, you can export [2] copies of some or all of your logs outside of Stackdriver Logging.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/basic-concepts

[2] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using PubSub(another project) for exporting the logs and then logging to the StackDriver with the subscriber.